Pandas の plot と matplotlib の plot を併用時、実行順によって意図した通り描画されない
PandasのDataFrameのplotメソッドでDataFrameを描画した後に、matplotlibのplotメソッドで他のリストデータを描画したところ、DataFrameのグラフは表示されましたが、matplotlibのplotメソッドで描画したグラフは表示されませんでした。
描画順を変更（[1]、[2]の実行順を逆にする）すると、正しく表示されました。
この振る舞いは仕様でしょうか、それともBugでしょうか？
（もしBugでしたら、みなさんのご意見聞いた上で、GitHubのIssueを発行しようかと思います。）
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

print(f'matplotlib version: {matplotlib.__version__}')
print(f'pandas version: {pd.__version__}')

df = pd.DataFrame(
    data=[
        {'data1': 3_000, 'data2': 3_500},
        {'data1': 3_200, 'data2': 3_600},
        {'data1': 3_100, 'data2': 3_700},
    ],
    index=[
        pd.Timestamp('2024-06-01 10:00'),
        pd.Timestamp('2024-06-01 12:00'),
        pd.Timestamp('2024-06-01 14:00')
    ]
)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

# [1]pandasでplot
df.plot(ax=ax)

# [2]matplotlibでplot
ax.plot(
    [pd.Timestamp('2024-06-01 10:00'), pd.Timestamp('2024-06-01 12:00'), pd.Timestamp('2024-06-01 14:00')],
    [3_600, 4_000, 3_400],
    linewidth=5.0
)
plt.show()

以下、実行結果です。

◇追記（似た事例がありましたのでリンクを追記します。）
pandasの時系列プロットの時間軸を、matplotlibでフォーマットし直す

何故似たようなデータに2つの手段(pandasのplotとmatplotlibのplot)を使う必要があるのでしょう？ 2つ目のデータもpandasのDataFrameにすれば良いのでは？

pandasのDataFrameをグラフ描画する処理をモジュール化できるとよいなと考えています。
そのモジュールは、さらに呼出し側からデータやマーカをカスタマイズして追加表示するなど、
動的に機能を拡張できるようにしたい、と思い質問いたしました。

この問題点に関して、以下のドキュメントで解説されています。
Suppressing tick resolution adjustment

pandas includes automatic tick resolution adjustment for regular frequency time-series data. For limited cases where pandas cannot infer the frequency information (e.g., in an externally created twinx), you can choose to suppress this behavior for alignment purposes.

具体的には、pandas.DataFrame.plot() メソッドに x_compat=True を指定します。
# [1]pandasでplot
# df.plot(ax=ax)
df.plot(ax=ax, x_compat=True)



ありがとうございます。期待した結果を得られました。x_compat引数が用意されていることから対策済(仕様)であること理解できました。

Timestamp 型のデータを X 軸として使う場合の変換が異なるためと思われます。試しに X 軸として使うデータを「pandas で plot」後の状況に合わせて変換してから「matplotlib で plot」すれば描画は可能なようです。
下記の記述例を参照ください。
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

print(f'matplotlib version: {matplotlib.__version__}')
# matplotlib version: 3.9.0
print(f'pandas version: {pd.__version__}')
# pandas version: 2.2.2

df = pd.DataFrame([{'data1': 3_000, 'data2': 3_500},
                   {'data1': 3_200, 'data2': 3_600},
                   {'data1': 3_100, 'data2': 3_700},],
                  index=[pd.Timestamp('2024-06-01 10:00'),
                         pd.Timestamp('2024-06-01 12:00'),
                         pd.Timestamp('2024-06-01 14:00')])

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(2, figsize=(8, 12))

# ax1 に matplotlib で plot 
ax1.plot(list(df.index), df['data1'], df['data2'])

print(ax1.get_xlim())
# (19875.408333333333, 19875.591666666667)

# ax1 に pandas で plot
pd.DataFrame([3_600, 4_000, 3_400], index=df.index
             ).plot(ax=ax1, linewidth=5.0, legend=False)

# ax2 に pandas で plot
df.plot(ax=ax2)

print(ax2.get_xlim())
# (477010.0, 477014.0)

# ax2 に matplotlib で plot，ただし，ax2 に合わせて x を変換
x = list(df.index.map(lambda x: x.timestamp() / 3600))
print(x)
# [477010.0, 477012.0, 477014.0]

ax2.plot(x, [3_600, 4_000, 3_400], linewidth=5.0)

plt.show()




ありがとうございます。再現できました。（回避することができました。） x軸用のデータ変換方法が異なること理解できました。 matplotlibはエポックからの経過日数、pandasはエポックからの経過時間数で、float型に変換しているようですね。 matplotlibでplotした後に、pandasでplotするときは、pandasはmatplotlibの尺度に合わせているけれど、 xlimが未設定の場合(デフォルトの0.0, 1.0の場合)は、matplotlibの尺度に合わせてくれないようにも解釈できました。
